# Como obtener el valor de dos columnas de un data table

Tags: c#, ado.net

Hola tengo un datatable llenado con un procedimiento almacenado, lo que quiero es solo obtener id de la factura y el nombre del cliente.

Por lo tanto este es mi codigo :

```
public void actualizaremail()
        {
            Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos con = new Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos();
            Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos cnd = new Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos();
            DataTable p = con.ListarFacturasObservadasBL();


            for (int i = 0; i < p.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //aca haces las operaciones con cada fila de la tabla ej:
                string id = p.Rows[i]["id_facturas"].ToString();
                string factura = p.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                cnd.ActualizarEmail(Convert.ToInt32(id), factura);

            }
```

Me sale el siguiente error ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No se que quieres lograr pero al ver un `ActualizarEmail()` dentro del `for` es indicativo que algo no es correcto

Si tienes un `DataTable` las rows se puede iterar usando

```
foreach(DataRow row in p.Rows){
    string id = Convert.ToString(row["id_facturas"]);

}
```

No se porque la variable `factura` la resuelves usando un indice de la columna `2` en lugar de aplicar el nombre como lo haces con `id_facturas` si es que conoces los nombres de las columnas que obtienes del datatable

Sino recuerda que puede poner un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionar el `datatable` usando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

usando el icono de la `lupa` y desplegando el `visualizer`

Comment: El metodo actualizarEmail recibe dos parametros , a lo que quiero llegar es darle esos dos valores del data table.

Comment: ok eso se entendio, pero porque trabajas diferente como obtienes los datos de datatable? entiendo los nombre de los campos los conoces, no ? si es asi accedelos usando el nombre no el numero

Comment: Ok . Ingrese con el nombre y me sale el mismo error .

Comment: Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos con = new Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos();
            Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos cnd = new Controlador.ControladorDatosNuevos();
            DataTable p = con.ListarFacturasObservadasBL();

            foreach (DataRow row in p.Rows)
            {
                string id = Convert.ToString(row["id_facturas"]);
                string factura= Convert.ToString(row["Cia"]); ;
                cnd.ActualizarEmail(Convert.ToInt32(id), factura);
            }

Comment: mi procedimiento almacenado es este :

Comment: mi sp procedure es este :   select 
 id_facturas ,
 nro_doc AS 'Nro. Factura', 
 cliente AS 'Cia',
 B.DAccidentado_Nombre +' '+B.DAccidentado_Apellido AS 'NOMBRE',
  emisor AS 'Centro Medico', 
  imp_bruto  AS 'Monto',
 b.IAM_AUDITORIANRO_REAL,
 isnull(fechaenvio,'') as fechaenvio,
 isnull(estadoemail,0) as estadoemail
    from SAMK.dbo.Facturas   as a
    inner join SAMK.[dbo].[AtencionMedica] as b
 on a.cKeyEncarNro_IDReg = b.cKeyEncarNro_IDReg
 where cestado = 'X'  and fech_MEDIK >='2018-08-01 00:00:00.000' and [bsituacion] is null

Comment: como controlas los errores? porque segun parece el mensaje del problema no es al acceder a los datos sino que es del procedure, si tomas el select y lo ejecutas en el management studio obtienes registros de respuesta?

Comment: has intentado poniendo un breakpoint en el codigo y ver si realmente se cargan registros en el datatable o si el fallo se produce antes

Comment: hola disculpa la respuesta de demora y si verifico que los datos del store procedure llenan mi datatable